# Advanced Android crash analysis?

Tags: android, debugging, crash, stack

Is there a way to get more useful information from an android crash? Deliberately inducing a UAF crash in android ICS I get the following output to my logcat, but is there a way to do a more complete stack dump and heap dump at the time of the crash? I can't seem to do it in ddms because as soon as the fatal signal is hit ddms abandons the process (because it doesn't exist anymore)

```
F/libc    (  598): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)
    I/DEBUG   (   33): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    I/DEUG   (   33): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:4.0.2/ICS_MR0/229537:eng/test-keys'
    I/DEBUG   (   33): pid: 598, tid: 621  >>> com.android.browser <<<
    I/DEBUG   (   33): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (   33):  r0 4b7824f0  r1 004b6da0  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (   33):  r4 00e8d7c0  r5 004b6da0  r6 00348370  r7 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (   33):  r8 49c61b10  r9 4afc808d  10 497df75d  fp 00108698
    I/DEBUG   (   33):  ip 00000000  sp 4b7824f0  lr 496bf215  pc 00000000  cpsr 20000010
    I/DEBUG   (   33):  d0  44750000cf000000  d1  44c1000000000000
    I/DEBUG   (   33):  d2  0000000044c10000  d3  4475000044750000
    I/DEBUG   (   33):  d4  0000000000000000  d5  44c1000000000000
    I/DEBUG   (   33):  d6  0000000000000000  d7  0000000000000000
    I/DEBUG   (   33):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  3fa999999999999a
    I/DEBUG   (   33):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
    I/DEBUG   (   33):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
    I/DEBUG   (   33):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    I/DEBUG   (   33):  scr 60000013
    I/DEBUG   (   33): 
    I/DEBUG   (   33):          #00  pc 00000000  
    I/DEBUG   (   33):          #01  pc 00191212  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    I/DEBUG   (   33):          #02  pc 001745c8  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    I/DEBUG   (   33):          #03  pc 002b1766  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    I/DEBUG   (   33):          #04  pc 004dccae  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    I/DEBUG   (   33):          #05  pc 004e052a  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    I/DEBUG   (   33):          #06  pc 004c3aae  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    I/DEBUG   (   33):          #07  pc 004c3b34  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    I/DEBUG   (   33): 
    I/DEBUG   (   33): code around pc:
    I/DEBUG   (   33): 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
    I/DEBUG   (   33): 00000010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
    I/DEBUG   (   33): 00000020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
    I/DEBUG   (   33): 00000030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
    I/DEBUG   (   33): 00000040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
    I/DEBUG   (   33): 
    I/DEBUG   (   33): code around lr:
    I/DEBUG   (   33): 496bf1f4 47904668 bd0e9801 68c3b507 b1134601 
    I/DEBUG   (   33): 496bf204 fc64f004 6800e005 20b0f8d0 47904668 
    I/DEBUG   (   33): 496bf214 bd0e9800 68c3b510 f004b113 e001fc49 
    I/DEBUG   (   33): 496bf224 fd18f7fe bf00bd10 68c3b510 f004b113 
    I/DEBUG   (   33): 496bf234 e001fc31 fd04f7fe bf00bd10 0124f1a1 
    I/DEBUG   (   33): 
    I/DEBUG   (   33): stack:
    I/DEBUG   (   33):     4b7824b0  00738f28  
    I/DEBUG   (   33):     4b7824b4  00348370  
    I/DEBUG   (   33):     4b7824b8  00000000  
    I/DEBUG   (   33):     4b7824bc  49c61b10  
    I/DEBUG   (   33):     4b7824c0  4afc808d  
    I/DEBUG   (   33):     4b7824c4  497df75d  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    I/DEBUG   (   33):     4b7824c8  00108698  
    I/DEBUG   (   33):     4b7824cc  49857421  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    I/DEBUG   (   33):     4b7824d0  00e7c388  
    I/DEBUG   (   33):     4b7824d4  00000000  
    I/DEBUG   (   33):     4b7824d8  00e7c388  
    I/DEBUG   (   33):     4b7824dc  498573f9  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    I/DEBUG   (   33):     4b7824e0  00e7c388  
    I/DEBUG   (   33):     4b7824e4  00000000  
    I/DEBUG   (   33):     4b7824e8  df0027ad  
    I/DEBUG   (   33):     4b7824ec  00000000  
    I/DEBUG   (   33): #01 4b7824f0  004b6da0  
    I/DEBUG   (   33):     4b7824f4  00000001  
    I/DEBUG   (   33):     4b7824f8  00000000  
    I/DEBUG   (   33):     4b7824fc  496a25cd  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the complete logs of the device by selecting `All messages(no filters)` option in Logcat.

[image]

Comment: I don't think I have any filters active, but even so, the logcat only outputs the above. I'm trying to do a complete stack and heap dump at time of crash, like might be possible on a windows machine.

Comment: When you launch an app, by default all the logs of that app is filtered under its package name. There is one option(All filters) which show all the logs. There you can find more details.

Comment: Oh I see, what is the syntax for that option, I do not see it in logcat --help

Comment: Ah, already got that set properly. I think its just that the logcat only provides so much information. Are there any more advanced debugging options? I'm still messing around with the Android Debug Monitor but its hard to obtain information about the crash since the monitor unlinks from the process when it crashes

Comment: Your code crashed due to execution of the callback which was not registered properly, i.e. was only initialized to NULL.

You may disassemble the libwebcore using objdump (or addr2line) to identify code from consecutive stack frames. You will find tools in prebuilts directory.